# Adding some padding to border in a textview

Tags: android, layout, textview

I'm trying to add a border to my textview. I did it as well:

```
<TextView
android:layout_below="@id/overviewHeader"
android:id="@+id/overviewTextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@layout/rounded_border_textview"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
tools:text="Twenty-two years ..."/>
```

And this is the background which I built:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <item android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="15dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="0.2dp"
                android:color="#ffffff"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</selector>
```

The problem is, that even if I set up a padding, the text is too close to the border:

[image]

How can I solve?

Comment: Add padding to textview.

Comment: You can set padding to your textview rather than giving padding to the background drawable

Comment: I would add a parent layout to the Textview (a constraint layout for instance) and then add the background to that layout, this way you can remove it from the TextView and add the proper margin in the parent layout to the Text view so the text is not so close to the border.

Comment: Thank you, I solved by adding padding to textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a padding value to your textview like so:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

[image]